# Button doesn't work when invisible

Tags: android, xml, layout, button

I have a background that i put in my app and there are places where the buttons are supposed to go. So when I get the buttons all lined up I turn the buttons to invisible so that they aren't seen when you open the app. But when I do that it is invisible but there is no invisible button their. I should just be able to click in the area where I put the button. Right?

Thanks for all your help!

```
Button
    android:id="@+id/start1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:height="75dp" 
    android:width="150dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp" 
    android:visibility="visible" **(After I switch this to invisible the button doesn't work)**
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Er.. why would you expect an invisible button to work?

Comment: wrong. An invisible button is for all intents not there

Comment: you cant click buttons whos visibility set to **invisible/gone**

Comment: sorry for the confusion I though that making it invisible would hide the button picture but the link would still be there to click on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the buttons background set to the background you want, you need the visibility as visible.

visible = visible. able to interact with
invisible = invisible. space by this view is still taken up but is not able to interact
gone = not there at all, no space taken up, not able to interact with